# How to add a small image on right side of text whatever font size it is?

Tags: ios, swift, font-size

I'm trying to achieve this on iOS using Swift and storyboards:

[image]

[image]

Notice that the image size on the right never changes, only the text font size changes depending on the user's default font size. I want the image to remain at the end of the label.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to create an extension on UILabel and append whatever image/icon to the end of the attributedText, something along these lines:

```
extension UILabel {
    func appendIcon() {
        let iconAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        iconAttachment.image = UIImage(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
  
        let iconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: iconAttachment)
    
        guard let attributedText = self.attributedText else { return }
  
        let currentString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
        currentString.append(iconString)
        self.attributedText = currentString
    }
}
```

And then call that programmatically.

```
label.appendIcon() // will need to create outlet
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to add spacing between the text and the image, without using an actual space " "? If I were to position my image at the beginning of the string, instead of the end for example...